# Get .txt files from Windows Phone 7 to a PC

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am able to  write to a .txt file in Windows Phone 7. I know I can read this file programmatically, but how will I be able to get this file to a PC? Where exactly is the file stored on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK comes with the `Isolated Storage Explorer` tool which allows you to read and write files from Isolated Storage. Learn about it's usage at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=vs.92).aspx

This assumes that you're wanting to do this with files you're creating for dev/testing purposes.

If you want to make an application which allows you to create files which users can access from teh PC you're out of luck. Instead you'd need to look at emailing the info from the file or distributing the file via the web.

Comment: Thanks alot Matt. Makes things more clearer. But is there a hack or a jailbroken version of retrieving files from the Windows Phone 7??

Comment: @Suppi I haven't heard of such a hack. There used to be a way but that got shut down. I don't look at the hacks much though as there is no value to me in doing things which can't go into Marketplace.